# Posting video to Facebook Application with Koala and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, koala

I am trying to post a video to a Facebook apps wall that was uploaded by the user using the Koala gem.

When I try to post the video using

```
put_connections("APP_ID", "APP_NAME:upload", video: "VIDEO_FILE")
```

I get this error:

```
OAuthException: (#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.
```

Here are my files:

### videos controller.rb

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @videos = Video.all
    end

    def new 
        @video = Video.new
    end

    def show
        @video = Video.find params[:id]
    end

def upload
        @video = Video.create params[:video]
        if @video
             @upload_info = save_video_new_video_url(video_id: @video.id)
        else
             render "/videos/new"
        end
  end

def save_video
    @video = Video.find params[:id]
    if params[:id]
        Video.begin_upload current_user.id, params[:file]
    else
        Video.delete_video @video 
    end
  redirect_to videos_path, :notice => "video successfully uploaded"
end

end
```

### video.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :completes,   where(:is_complete => true)
    scope :incompletes, where(:is_complete => false)


    def self.begin_upload user_id, video_file
        user = User.find user_id
        video = user.facebook.put_connections(FB_CONFIG['app_id'], "thecomfortmovement:upload", video: File.expand_path(video_file.tempfile.to_path.to_s))
    end


    def self.delete_incomplete_videos
        self.incompletes.map{|r| r.destroy}
    end

    def self.delete_video video
        vid = Video.find video
        vid.destroy
     end

end
```

I am using the omniauth-facebook gem to authenticate the users as seen in this screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I am definitely still logged in so that should mean that the session and oauth token are still valid. Any suggestions?

### Update

Here is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
        user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
        user.save!
     end
   end

   def facebook
        @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
   end

end
```

### Update 2

This is the controller that im using to set and remove sessions:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_url
    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

Comment: What is user.facebook?? Are you saving the complete Koala class of the user in user.facebook? As per the new Facebook rules the token is valid only for 24 hours after you get it. Can you please put the steps where you are actually saving the complete facebook object of the user.

Comment: @ShreyasAgarwal Just added the contents of my User model, thanks for the reply. The way I was using it is something like: `User.find(session[:user_id]).facebook.put_connections(...)`

Comment: @ShreyasAgarwal also added my sessions controller

Comment: try adding this in your User Model @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(**self**.oauth_token)